# Need a simple solution for video podcasting

Tags: videos

Any suggestions for video capture programs for creating podcasts?  I just need something simple and haven't had luck with VLC or Shotcut.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install OBS Studio using:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio`

Version: 0.15.2
Released: July 15th, 2016

Official Site: https://obsproject.com

Comment: OBS looks like it'll meet my needs.  Thanks for responding.